# How to add overlay to Google map via ajax call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

Working with gmaps4rails and Rails 3.2 and trying to add an overlay on top of Google maps when the user clicks a checkbox "Show Radius" and then a circle would show up on the map with a certain radius around the user's location.

I know how to create the JS callbacks tied to the Google map created via gmaps4rails, but how do I retrieve the map from the DOM within the rails controller itself?

Presumably, I'd like to call some "showCircle" function within the .js.erb template or something similar.

Comment: ack, I think this is working by just calling Gmaps.map in my js template

Comment: You'll het the js object representing your map with: `Gmaps.map.serviceObject`